# Elixir ensure value is not 0 or nil

Tags: elixir

In this function, I need to check if the "price" variable is 0 or nil before I convert it into a float by doing `priceFloat = price / 1`, or I get an arithmetic error.

```
  def insert_product_shop(conn, product_id, shop_id, price) do
    IO.inspect(price, label: "price")
    priceFloat = price / 1 
    changeset = Api.ProductShop.changeset(%Api.ProductShop{p_id: product_id, s_id: shop_id, not_in_shop_count: 0, price: priceFloat})
    errors = changeset.errors
    valid = changeset.valid?
    case insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, product_shop} ->
        {:ok, product_shop}
      {:error, changeset} ->
        {:error, :failure}
    end
  end
```

What is an idiomatic way to do so?

I tried this but I still get the arithmetic error:

```
  def insert_product_shop(conn, product_id, shop_id, price) do
    IO.inspect(price, label: "price")
    case {price} do 
      {price} when price > 0 ->
        priceFloat = price / 1 
        changeset = Api.ProductShop.changeset(%Api.ProductShop{p_id: product_id, s_id: shop_id, not_in_shop_count: 0, price: priceFloat})
        errors = changeset.errors
        valid = changeset.valid?
        case insert(changeset) do
          {:ok, product_shop} ->
            {:ok, product_shop}
          {:error, changeset} ->
            {:error, :failure}
        end
      end
  end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is because in Elixir, `nil > 0` is true. You can do this instead:

```
if price not in [0, nil] do
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

or

```
if is_number(price) and price > 0 do
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic way to do this would be to pattern match directly in function clauses:

```rb
def insert_product_shop(conn, product_id, shop_id, price)
  when not is_number(price), do: {:error, :nil}
def insert_product_shop(conn, product_id, shop_id, price)
  when price <= 0, do: {:error, :not_positive}
def insert_product_shop(conn, product_id, shop_id, price) do
  priceFloat = price / 1
  changeset = 
    Api.ProductShop.changeset(
      %Api.ProductShop{p_id: product_id,
                       s_id: shop_id,
                       not_in_shop_count: 0,
                       price: priceFloat})
  errors = changeset.errors
  valid = changeset.valid?

  case insert(changeset) do
    {:ok, product_shop} ->
      {:ok, product_shop}
    {:error, changeset} ->
      {:error, :failure}
  end
end
```

First two clauses might be collapsed into one with a guard

```rb
when not is_number(price) or price <= 0
```

Comment: Thanks. It produced this error though. `no case clause matching: nil`

Comment: This is impossible. The error is induced, please show the exact line it happens.

Comment: Ah, got it. Your caller expects the `{:error, _}` as a response. See the corrected variant. Please note, that your initial attempt also had this glitch.

Comment: It's now returning the expected values and works. Thanks!

Comment: I think I will still insert into the database in the case the price is 0 or nil. But I can make this change. Cheers

Comment: The question I answered was “What would be an idiomatic way to handle zeroes and nils in the input.” I provided an idiomatic solution. Honestly, I could not care less about how you are going to handle your data in the future :)